# Why is the vector cross product different here?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mathematics

I was taught that the linear velocity of a body rotating around a fixed axis is the cross product between the angular velocity and the position vector.
The vector for the velocity here in this picture is at the end of the position vector:
[image]

While in this picture its at the origin?

[image]

Im confused. Does it matter where the linear velocity vector is as long as its perpendicular to both the angular velocity and the position vector? Does its location matter?

Many thanks

S.M

Comment: Vectors don't have a location. They have a magnitude and a direction; that's all, nothing else. Or in other words, they are just lists of numbers. So you can move them anywhere.

Comment: but how about the position vector r?  Im confused. I thought vectors are fixed

Comment: No, it doesn't have a location. A position vector is a vector that shows a particle's location when it is anchored to the origin. But the vector itself has nothing to do with the origin. It just has a magnitude and a direction. Or it just has three numbers (in a 3d world).

Comment: So provided that the position vector r is perpendicular to the angular velocity, can you stick the linear velocity where ever you like?

Comment: You will get a vector after the cross-product operation. Deciding how to show this vector graphically is up to you. You can put it on anywhere. The vector is the same, but the graphical representation may be different and has no mathematical meaning.

Comment: By the way, I just noted that the direction of v is wrong in the second figure. You won't get that vector after the cross-product operation. But putting it on the origin is fine.

Comment: So as long as the conditions are met you can stick the new vector anywhere?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the conditions meeting anything. You have a vector. This vector has magnitude and direction information in it, nothing else. If you want to show this vector graphically, you can put it anywhere. The vector is perfectly presented as long as it has the same magnitude and direction. Look at it this way: Let's say you have a vector <1, 0, 0>. Let's assume it is anchored to the origin. Then what would be the vector with the same magnitude and direction that is anchored to the point x=1, y=5, z=1? It will again be <1, 0, 0>, the same thing! Vectors don't have start points.

Answer (score 2):

the main difference between the two is that there is no origin in the second graph (or point that linear velocity is calculated with respect of). That makes the second diagram a bit confusing.

However the second diagram - at least to me is wrong- because it doesn't comply with the right hand rule. Given that $\vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}$, the direction of the velocity should be opposite on the second diagram (on the first one is correct).

Comment: So the velocity should be pointing towards the right on the second diagram. But why is the linear velocity in the middle or at the start rather than on the edge of the position vector?

Comment: because there is no origin in this diagram. I think the creator of this diagram wanted to demonstrate the orthoganality and treated the vectors in a more liberal way. The more correct representation is the first one.